# Eclipse 2021-03 - why javascript does not appear within the preferences menu?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

After installed eclipse IDE 2021 03, all my php projects containing javascript files are seen as containing a lot of errors (> 15000) for eclipse.
I wanted to configure javascript parser but can't find any entry within the "preferences" menu.
In the same time I need to select the generic editor to get syntax coloring.
When I check what is installed I see that
JavaScript Development Tools    2.3.400.v202102101628
is installed.
Can you tell me what I must do to correct that?

Comment: There are two different JavaScript language supports by two different Eclipse projects: WTP JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT) is when using the JavaScript editor, Eclipse Wild Web Developer is when using the Generic Text Editor (preferences: _Languages Servers_).

Comment: Thanks howlger, both are installed and I may choose between text editor and generic text editor to open a .js file. Default text editor does not colorize the code, and errors are wrongly reported :( reported

Answer (score 0):

I still do not have javascript specific configuration menu entry but I resolved both ( errors and colorization ) by uninstalling jsdt and wild web developer , and reinstalling only wild web developer.
Now the colorization is done by default when I open a js file, and all the "false" errors disappeared.